# How to rename connected computer monitors in linux using wayland?

Tags: linux, gnome, display, multi-monitor, wayland

I have two identical computer monitors, both from the same manufacturer, with matching models and revisions. These monitors are connected to a Thunderbolt 4 docking station via DisplayPort, and the docking station is linked to a notebook computer that supports Thunderbolt 4. This configuration results in three total displays. When I use applications that support screen sharing, such as video conferencing apps or websites with WebRTC capabilities, it becomes confusing to identify each monitor. The issue is exacerbated because both monitors connected to the docking station are named *Acer Technologies 27"*.

**How to rename these displays in order to alleviate the confusion?**

The screensharing selection prompt looks like this Fedora 38 with Gnome 44 and Wayland:

[image: Gnome Screen Sharing Display Selector]

The display names are also shown in the gnome display settings:

[image: Gnome Display Settings]

Comment: Seems like we have to wait for the feature of screen previews, there is no workaround at the moment: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/xdg-desktop-portal-gnome/-/issues/9

Comment: Thanks for posting this gitlab issue link. Screen thumbnail previews are even better than custom display names.